# Avoiding the use of 'new' in this situation

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class ContentLoader, which basically keeps track of all content and makes sure there's only one instance of each class that doesn't need more than one instance active.

But I have a problem:

```
class ContentLoader
{
private:
    std::map<const char*, GFX::Material*> m_Materials;
    typedef std::pair<const char*, GFX::Material*> MTLPAIR;

public:
    ContentLoader();
    virtual ~ContentLoader();

    void RegisterMaterial(GFX::Material* mtl, const char* szName);
    GFX::Material* GetMaterial(const char* szName);
};
```

GFX::Material is a base class where multiple classes (materials) inherit from.
However, in order to pass one material to RegisterMaterial(), one must use 'new Specific_Material()'. We can not just copy a GFX::Material object because it would only copy the data contained in the base class.

Is there a way around this, so I don't need to use 'new' to pass a material to the contentloader? If yes, how?

Comment: Using `char const*`s as keys in a map seems like a really bad idea. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: c string? It's working though, why the concern?

Comment: `std::map` will treat the `char const*`s as pointers, not as strings. If you are using string literals in the call to `RegisterMaterial` and `GetMaterial`, there is no guarantee that the addresses of the string literals used in each call will match up. If you are using pointers to dynamically allocated strings, there is no chance at all that the addresses of different strings with the same content will be equal.

Comment: @Mankarse I see the reason for your concern, however it works properly. Maybe `the operator <` of const char* behaves differently than 'other' pointers?

Comment: @xcrypt, no, it may work correctly only in case if your compiler unites same strings (i.e. puts them to the same memory location). operators = and < behave same as for any other pointer type

Comment: @xcrypt: It doesn't work properly. You just got unlucky and were not able to observe any of the bugs that your code contains.

Comment: Wait, is this asking how to implement a singleton?

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you a trick which is more of a hack to get around this. Seems like you are building a prototype factory based on the prototype pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern

What you can do is, declare a static instance of each of your specialized classes and in each specialized class's constructor call RegisterMaterial. For example for Specific_Material.cpp you would have:

```
SpecificMaterial SpecificMaterial::specificMaterialInstance;
```

where specificMaterialInstance is a static data member of SpecificMaterialInstance.

In essence, all these classes will "self-register".

The problem with this method is that the order in which your static instances will be created is compiler dependent. For example I remember some VC++ compilers would just do it based on the alphabetical names of the modules so SpecificMaterialA instance would be constructed before SpecificMaterialB, so you have some loss of control.

I have implemented it for a Master's thesis project about 10 yrs before, so I know it works.

Comment: Singleton would solve the order in which your static instances are created, right?

Comment: But really, that would indeed work Sid, but one of the reasons we use these shiny loader classes is to avoid doing what you just described, because it's sort of messy x) I actually did that first but because it was a little messy I switched to a loader approach

Comment: @xcrypt agreed it is messy. Is your real issue that you don't want to call new or that you don't want explicitly register? You could have static variables again and register while instead of accepting pointers, accept references.

Comment: Well It's not really a 'problem' I'm having. But I would like to unite the performant way of not using 'new' with not having the messy approach of the static variables.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the use of sub-typing as an implementation detail.

There is a set of operations that you might want to do on a `GFX::Material`, so make the `GFX::Material` class implement those operations (I don't know what they are, but here's a guess at some):

```
//These can be automatically generated,
//but they are still part of the interface [
//Copy construct and assign
GFX::Material(GFX::Material const&);
GFX::Material& operator=(GFX::Material const&);
//Move construct and assign
GFX::Material(GFX::Material&&);
GFX::Material& operator=(GFX::Material&&);
//Destruct
GFX::~Material();
]
//Draw
void draw(Canvas& canvas, vec<2, float> posision);

//Stretch
void stretch(vec<2, float> scale);

//...
```

Now, to set up how the GFX::Material responds to each of these operations - give it a parameterised constructor:

```
GFX::Material(/*Data to set up how I behave*/);
```

Now there is no more need to pass pointers into `ContentLoader`, `GFX::Material` knows how to correctly copy itself, move itself, and perform other operations that depend on its value.

---

With this done, `ContentLoader` can be rewritten as:

```
class ContentLoader
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, GFX::Material> m_Materials;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, GFX::Material> MTLPAIR;

public:
    ContentLoader();
    ~ContentLoader();

    void RegisterMaterial(GFX::Material mtl, std::string szName);
    GFX::Material& GetMaterial(std::string const& szName);
};
```

---

So how would `GFX::Material` actually be implemented?

From the looks of it, you are expecting the range of possible behaviours for `GFC::Material` to be highly variable. If that is the case, it would probably be best to implement it as an object which holds a pointer to another object which can hold variable data and functions. This could be implemented through inheritance:

```
struct MaterialImplementaton {
    //Copy:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<MaterialImplementaton> clone() const = 0;
    //Destroy:
    virtual ~MaterialImplementaton() {}
    //Draw
    virtual void draw(Canvas& canvas, vec<2, float> posision) = 0;

    //Stretch
    virtual void stretch(vec<2, float> scale) = 0;

    //...
};
```

Now you can pass a `unique_ptr<MaterialImplementaton>` into `GFX::Material(/*Data to set up how I behave*/)` to set up the behaviour. GFX::Material would hold a `clone_ptr<MaterialImplementation>`, and just forward calls on to the `MaterialImplementation`.

This is but one of many possible implementations for `GFX::Material`. The important thing is that `GFX::Material` is able to properly contain all the operations which it needs to perform.

Comment: In your implementation, are you not just moving the problem towards the MaterialImplementation? I would have to use 'new' for the MaterialImplementation, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @xcrypt it is nasty but it could be down with a boost::varient and an enum.

Comment: @xcrypt: The problem hasn't just been moved to `MaterialImplementation`, it is also no longer a problem. `new` isn't something which is totally evil and which should be avoided at all costs, it is just something which is easy to misuse. If you really want to avoid `new`, you could use some other technique to customise the behaviour of `GFX::Material`, that was what I was trying to imply by the comment in the declaration: `GFX::Material(/*Data to set up how I behave*/);`.

Comment: I'm not saying `new` is something which is totally evil and which should be avoided at all cost, but it is indeed easily misused. The only good reason to use it is to provide dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

you would still need `new` however if the map own the material then you should use smart pointers to reflect this.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<GFX::Material> mat_ptr_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, mat_ptr_t> mat_map_t;
mat_map_t materials;

materials["treecolouredstuff"]=mat_ptr_t(new WildernessMaterial());
```

UNTESTED

When the element is removed from the map or the map is destroyed, the memory is automatically cleaned up.

Comment: it's not about the cleanup, it's about the performance loss. You are right considering the reflection of the map owning the materials, but it doesn't answer my question.